Let's encrypt throwing Error 'Cached order has status invalid' for IIS Server
I am error while creating Let's Encrypt SSL certificate for my domain app.mysite.io using win-acme (wacs).
I am using IIS server for deployments and bindings.
The Domain is already pointed to my server and the Ping is also successful,

when I try to create Let's Encrypt SSL certificate I am getting the Cached order has status invalid error.
Port 80 and Port 443 are enable in firewall as well.

Additionally, I have successfully created SSL certificate before as well on same machine using same method, they were success.
my these domains are working fine with SSL enabled:

portal.mysite.io.
api.mysite.io.

Moreover, I am facing this issue not with just app.mysite.io Domain but also any other new domain like app.mysite.biz

Did any configuration changes to IIS occur since you last successfully created a certificate? Perhaps you can look at this similar case:https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certfificate-generation-failure/217960

Thank you for your response! the port 80 was closed by my network provider, they will soon enable it and solve the issue.

ANSWER:
As i checked telnet on my site on port 80 the Connection failed
C:\Users\IBM User>telnet insigniafleet.insigniabiz.com 80       
Connecting To insigniafleet.insigniabiz.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 80: Connect failed

As I contacted my Network Service Provider and it turns out that they disabled port 80 from there side few days ago , due to some reasons (which was enable before).
It was working on my home network but not on any other network
So now they are working on it and it soon will be enable.
